# jquery's mouseover/out function only works after click-event in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

When creating a mouseover/out action on an span in my html it appeared that there is no interaction with the link, up until I first click the element; after which the over/out events are almost simultanuously fired.

The simple javascript works both in Chrome and FirefoxDeveloperEdition; but the new quantum release displays this strange  behaviour.

Anybody else experiencing this?

```
$(".item")
.mouseover(function(ev){
    console.log('over');
  })
.mouseout(function(ev) {
    console.log('out');
})
.click(function (ev) {
    console.log('click');
})

<span class="item">click me</span>
```

Comment: The code works just find for me http://jsbin.com/dohoronelu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Works for me, too. The only caveat is that you do have to have the browser "active" (like if I'm typing on my second monitor and then try to mouseover the browser on the first, it wouldn't work unless I first alt-tab to the browser or otherwise make it active by clicking into it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. Thanks for thinking along, your remark @delinear set me on the right path.

I was working in the responsive mode of the browser... apparently it then doesn't fire the mouseover/mouseout events :(