# jQuery - sound on mouseover not working correctly

Tags: jquery, html, audio, mouseevent, mouseover

I am making a website for kids, i want that when someone will hover on link that will play a sound.

Here is my code-

```
<audio id="hoverA">
  <source src="files/sound/hover-01.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

jQuery code-

```
var hoverA = document.getElementById("hoverA");
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".navbar .nav-link").mouseover(function(){
    hoverA.play();
  });
});
```

Sound is playing well only if first i am doing some activity on page like click keyboard, click mouse etc.
After refresh it stop working, playing only if again i am doing some activity.

Comment: Could you show where your jQuery code is being called in your HTML document? and also is your jQuery code that you mentioned above within a function or just like in your post: i.e. a script file?

Comment: it is same, no additional code. page name is scripts.js inside js folder.

Comment: and audio code is in the index.php. I am linking scripts.js through script src in the index page

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you exactly want to hapen when someone begins to hover over the link there will be two methods with jQuery I would suggest. For future readers or reference I think it is useful to put both of these jQuery features down.

---

## Hover

Use the built in .hover function from jQuery. You can see a similar example on [JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TPQTq/)

```
var hoverA = document.getElementById("hoverA");
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar .nav-link").hover(function () {
        hoverA.play();
    });
});
```

## On Enter / Leave

If you wanted it to start on the enter area or leave area.

```
var hoverA = document.getElementById("hoverA");
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".navbar .nav-link").mouseenter(function () {
            hoverA.play();
        }).mouseleave(function ()
        {
            hoverA.play();
        });
});
```

---

I believe using the .hover function would work best, as with .mouseover I thought it needed to register user interaction first.

Hopefully this helps! :)

**EDIT 1:**

After checking it appears to a browser issue as discussed in a similar SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311888/jquerys-mouseover-out-function-only-works-after-click-event-in-firefox). It states:

> I was working in the responsive mode of the browser... apparently it
>   then doesn't fire the mouseover/mouseout events

This appeared to be the issue to getting the events fired in jQuery.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replay, if i am inserting console.log("work") inside hover script that gives a output but only sound gives problem. i had tried all these three method(hover,mouseover,mouseenter), but all has same problem.

Comment: What is the problem with the sound? It wont play anything?

Comment: playing well but after some activity on page like click or press keyboards

Comment: @VikashSDNT See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47311888/jquerys-mouseover-out-function-only-works-after-click-event-in-firefox) post to check it's not your browser

Comment: bro it was my browser problem.

Comment: @VikashSDNT Ahh perfect! I've updated my answer to include this solution in the bottom. Could you please mark it as correct as this was the correct fix?

Comment: I get problem again. Now i think it is my computer's problemn.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be helpful: [css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/play-sound-on-hover/)

```js
var beepOne = $("#beep-one")[0];
$("#nav-one a")
 .mouseenter(function() {
  beepOne.play();
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="nav-one" class="nav">
     <li>
      <a href="#">Item 0</a>
      <audio id="beep-one" preload="auto">
    <source src="http://codeskulptor-demos.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/descent/gotitem.mp3"></source>
    <source hrfe="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/jump.ogg"></source>
    Your browser isn't invited for super fun time.
   </audio>
   </li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: i Think it is my browser problem.

Comment: @VikashSDNT which browser are you using?

Comment: I have noticed that the .ogg link sound was not working, I have tried to link a different sound for the ogg one.

Comment: chrome latest version

Comment: hmmm that's strange as I am using Chrome latest version too and it seems to work just fine